# Using arrow keys to navigate a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uikeycommand

I would like to be able to traverse a `UITableView` using a physical keyboard's arrow keys then use the enter key to select a row. Normally the user would type into a `UISearchBar` then select a result without taking their hands off the keyboard.

Is there any easier way other than using a `UIKeyCommand` for each of these? This method is already implemented in the main view controller, so I don't want to override that by also having it in another view controller, and ideally I don't want to need to call methods in this other view controller from the main class either.

Using Objective-C.

Thank you.